# Ajax.BeginForm InsertionMode.ReplaceWith не заменяет весь элемент DOM

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Сделал пошаговую форму, где в элемент Steps записывались данные из контрола.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(Action, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "Steps",
    }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="row">
            <div id="Steps">

            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn center" value="Перейти к следующему шагу" />
        </div>
    }
```

Новые данные вставляются внутрь элемента . Так и должно, но мне надо чтобы и сам элемент DOM заменялся. 
Данный AjaxHelper содержит InsertionMode.ReplaceWith, но не работает и сам элемент DOM не удаляется и загруженная информация из контрола вставляется внутрь элемента. И в msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.insertionmode(v=vs.118).aspx нет ReplaceWith, хотя в студии есть. Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Ответ с сервера будет вставляться внутрь тега с `id`

Comment: Знаю, но ReplaceWith подразумевает что будет заменяться и сам элемент, но этого не происходит. Получается что ReplaceWith дублирует просто Replace

Comment: Какая у вас версия Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax?

Comment: Unobtrusive - 3.2.3. Помогла переустановка Microsoft.Owin